# Why does my swift project look different on my device vs. the simulator?

Tags: ios, xcode, device, simulator

I am working on a xcode project and when I run the app on the simulator everything looks as it should but when I run it on my real device (iphone 7) the changes I made in the storyboard are not applied.

I changed the text on the tab bar on one of the tabs from "kort" to "favoritter" and on the simulator this applies but on my device the text is still "kort" as before.

I have tried to delete the app from my device and clean the build from xcode and then install it again but it did not help.

Does anyone know why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: make sure you did not use size classes in storyboard. It could be the case.

Comment: Just delete that storyboard in which changes are not reflecting and take new storyboard instead it will start reflecting changes.

Comment: It helped just deleting the storyboard and replacing it with a new one! Thank you for the help!